# Cannot figure out the output of my array list

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

This might be a dumb question but its frustrating me. I am adding into my array list a object during a loop but outside of the loop, all of the array list is overwritten with the last element in the array. It goes something like this.

```
while(fin.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = fin.nextLine();
    String[] user = line.split(",");
    r.add(new User(user[0], user[1]));
    System.out.println(r.get(count).getName());
    count++;
}
```

This gives me an output of something like this (USER1, USER2, USER3, etc.) during the loop.
However, right after the loop I now have an output of something like this (USER500, USER500, USER500).

```
while(fin.hasNextLine())
{
    String line = fin.nextLine();
    String[] user = line.split(",");
    r.add(new User(user[0], user[1]));
    System.out.println(r.get(count).getName());
    count++;
}

for (int i  =0; i < r.size(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(r.get(i).getName());
}
```

I managed to verify that this is the class where I'm having the problem and only one other method uses the array list in this class which i commented out.

Comment: Where is r defined? you might print out its size() to check it has the right number of entries

Comment: Something is amiss in the code.. Can you post full code please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm going to have to put on my psychic debugging goggles, but I predict tht your `User` class looks like this:

```
public class User {
    private static String name;

    public User(String x, String somethingElse) {
        name = x;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Note that `name` is static. Therefore that's *one* variable - not one per *instance* of `User`. You want it to be an *instance* field, so that each `User` object has a different name variable.

Comment: Thanks. That was exactly it. I can't believe I missed it before.